# Ошибки при подключении D3

Tags: javascript, библиотеки

Ошибка "NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI: Access to restricted URI denied d3.v3.min.js:1".
Я пытался найти информацию о решении этой ошибки - но все что дало рытье в интернетах, это то что такая ошибка вызвана кроссдоменным запросом. Вот тут и вопрос. Что я не так делаю? Кроссдоменного запроса у меня в коде нет, весь код - тупо копипаста вот отсюда - http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/3/ . Скопировал, вставил в локальный html-файл. Содержание - http://pastebin.com/7eJYVyYM . Запускаю локально Лисой последней версии, выдает ошибку, названную выше. Спасибо, если что-то знаете)

Comment: Или у меня в коде есть кроссдоменный запрос, но я об этом не догадываюсь???)

Comment: @uakob
У вас, я так понимаю, подгружается файл `data.tsv`? Так вот, вы его забыли создать :)

Comment: спасибо, я не заметил этого сначала) и в доках почему-то нет ничерта про это (возможно позже, но там где я читал - не заметил). буду копать дальше)